# How to handle lots of unchanging backing data that is kind of unrelated to my application

Tags: database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

**Background**

I'm creating a layered .net core application to handle tracking campaigns for a board game. Because of this there is a lot of data that comes from the game itself, for example:

- Characters
- Weapons
- Equipment
- Missions
- Objectives that belong to a mission
- Rewards that belong to objectives
- Etc

The application is not to manipulate this data. This data is typically printed on cards that come with the board game so it won't change. The only changes it may have are when I manually add new characters or something due to a new expansion being released.

As far as the app is concerned, these are similar to how you might have a lookup table of States in the US. The app needs to list them so you can select them, entities in the domain hold references to them, but their actual data is irrelevant to the application itself. It's just lookup data.

Except there is a lot of this data and some of it is related. For example an objective belongs to a specific mission and a reward belongs to a specific objective.

**The Problem**

If my application was being designed to manage this data there would be no problem. However this is not the case. It is designed to manage "Campaigns", which are 2-5 players sitting down to play a game with these cards. It is managing "instances" of this data that have additional properties.

For example a new campaign is created and a row is added to the Campaign table. Now a mission must be added to it.

I can't just add a reference to the Mission data because I also need to store the outcome of the mission specific to this campaign. So I create a CampaignMission entity that references the mission data, the campaign id, and has a column for the mission outcome.

But that Mission data had related Objective data. The data just holds things like objective name, description, rewards etc, but in the campaign I also need to store the outcome of this objective specific to this CampaignMission. So again I create a CampaignObjective that references the Objective data, the CampaignMission, and has a column for the objective outcome.

Before you know it I am doing this for everything. CampaignCharacter, CampaignWeapon, CampaignReward. I feel like I'm just replicating the structure of the game data, relationships included.

Where the game data has relationships, my Campaign entities feel like they're mirroring the relationships to the point where, from the same object, you can access the same piece of game data by following two separate paths, the original game data relationship or the Campaign entity "replica" relationship.

For example if I want the name of the first reward for the first objective in the first campaign mission, you can access it in two ways:

```
Campaign.CampaignMissions[0].Mission.Objectives[0].Rewards[0].Name
Campaign.CampaignMissions[0].CampaignObjectives[0].CampaignRewards[0].Reward.Name
```

Both of these point to the same piece of game data. I really feel like there should only be one path:

```
Campaign.Missions[0].Objectives[0].Rewards[0].Name
```

**Where I'm Stuck**

I'm not sure if this is normal but it all just feels wrong. Almost as though the game data shouldn't even be part of the application. I mean the game data could be hosted on some 3rd party API and it wouldn't make any difference to my actual application. It's just data I need to read but I feel it's impacting my app structure in ways it shouldn't be.

My application doesn't really need to know the difference between Mission game data and a Mission in a campaign. All it needs to care about is that a campaign can have missions, and those missions have a name etc and an outcome. It doesn't feel like the Mission game data itself needs to be an entity in my domain.

**What I've Tried**

I tried keeping single entities in my domain and keeping them separate in my database. So for example a Mission in the domain would include both the game data fields like mission name, the mission outcome and a list of domain Objectives.

When a domain Mission for a campaign is requested from the data layer, the entry is retrieved from the CampaignMission table, along with its game data from the Mission table, then flattened via AutoMapper and returned to the domain as a single Mission entity containing everything.

This just caused a bit of a nightmare with Entity Framework and handling the mappings back and forth between data layer and domain because the CampaignMission in the database also had CampaignObjectives which linked to Objectives that also had to be flattened etc, and I had to keep track of the primary keys for all of these throughout my domain so everything could be unflattened and mapped back again when I want to persist something. It just didn't make sense, in terms of tracking primary keys/identity, for a single domain entity to be represented by entries in multiple tables.

**What I'm Now Considering**

I'm considering just moving all of the game data into a totally separate project, completely unrelated to my application. My application could then query project as though it was some third party API or something and get any data it needs and I can keep it all out of my solution.

Since the game data would no longer have IDs in my application, when I add a mission to a campaign it would simply have a column for "name" which would hold the mission name. When I want to use that mission I would grab it from the db and map it to a domain entity, so at this point it contains the campaign-specific data such as mission outcome, and also the name. Then I'd query the game data project using the mission name and map all the returned data back on to the entity as well, leaving me with a complete entity.

This is essentially replicating the behaviour of what I already tried but removing the need to track identity for the game data by simply using a name that I can query. It removes the concept of backing game data from my domain and leaves me with a single entity, Mission.

**The Question**

I've wasted a lot of time on this so far and I'm sure it must be a common problem in similar types of applications. I was wondering if anyone had a better solution for dealing with this kind of situation before I go ahead and try completely separating the data.

I have to admit, typing out the "What I'm Now Considering" section has clarified a few things for myself but I would still love to hear if there is a better way.

Thank you in advance if anyone reads all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you should be doing. First, add the game data entities to the `DbContext` as `DbQuery<T>`:

```
public DbQuery<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
```

This will allow you to query it, but will not allow changes. Then, since the game data is static, you might want to actually just persist it on a singleton, which you can then inject where you need it.

In either case, on the actual campaign data that's being persisted, you should only store the id of the game data concept. For example, `MissionId`, not `CampaginMission.Mission`. When you need the actual `Mission` info, just look it up based on the `MissionId`, either directly from your `DbQuery<Mission>` property on your context or your singleton class.

Comment: Do you think I should still map the game data to the domain model? Otherwise I have to pass it as a separate object from what I can see.

For example if I want to load a campaign with all its missions, and each CampaignMission only holds an Id to the game data instead of a navigation property that can be populated, then where do I put the actual game data for the mission when I send a campaign? I would have my Campaign object that contains CampaignMissions, and a bunch of mission data that I just queried separately, but nowhere in my CampaignMission to put that data.

Comment: What you're really dealing with is two bounded contexts: game and campaign. They share common entities, but those entities have different meanings in each context. You don't cross bounded contexts. Instead you implement an anti-corruption layer that can essentially speak both languages.

Comment: In true DDD fashion all the data from a game mission that's relevant to a campaign mission should exist on the campaign mission. Through the concept of eventual consistency, you can sync that data from game mission to campaign mission if you need to keep it up to date. Otherwise, you just reference the game mission id, and use that as a hook to pull the data you need, when you need it. That's not technically kosher with DDD, but it does make things easier.

Comment: "all the data from a game mission that's relevant to a campaign mission should exist on the campaign mission" is exactly where I was struggling, but I don't want all the game data duplicated in the database in every row of a campaign entity. I think I will go with your approach of having a missionId on the campaign mission, along with any campaign-specific data such as mission outcome. These will be in the campaign mission table.

Comment: Then the campaign mission domain model will also include all the data fields for a game mission, but they will not be stored in the campaign mission table and will initially be empty when a campaign mission is loaded. I will then hydrate the model by mapping the game data to it from the singleton (which I guess is the job of said anti-corruption layer?) so my app will never know any different. Similar to what I already tried but without having to go through navigation properties which messes everything up. Thanks so much, also thanks for DbQuery, I didn't know it existed.